# CSS columns: continue right sidebar and two columns to one

Tags: html, css

I need some help with layout as I am new to this.   Im basically need a three column layout underneath my horizontal nav bar, but I need to cut the first two columns off so that I can have a "text block" underneath them without affecting the continuing right side bar.  I can do this with a table but I would prefer not to if there is another way.

Comment: what exactly have you tried?

Comment: do you have HTML/CSS or jsfiddle?

Comment: I would look hard at some of the css grid frameworks they make this kind of problem trivial (bootstrap, 960 grid or just google css grid).

Comment: If you're open to using a framework, I can recommend [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/). Plus there are great resources for it like [LayoutIt](http://www.layoutit.com/) -- But if you're not into that then I'm just rambling

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/sJWKE/ Is this the effect you're looking for?

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    header
    </div>
    <div id="colWrap">
        <div class="col">
        column 1
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        column 2
        </div>
        <div id="text">
        text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        column 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is what I am after except I need text1 to span across col1 and col2

Comment: Updated :) to what I think is what you wanted

Comment: Thank you so much.  Thats exactly what I wanted!!  Awesome.